# Recursive list of permutations

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I want to solve a problem by recursion. I have a given list of letters and I want to have all permutations of these letters till a given length is reached.

```
var letters= ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];  
function myRekursion(alphabet, n){  
    if(n > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
            document.write(letters[i]);
            myRekursion(letters, n - 1);
        }
        document.write(",<br>");
    }
}
myRekursion(letters,3);
```

I can't figure out why I run through the full list all the time instead of creating a list like: AAA,AAB,AAC,...,FFF

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: "alphabet" should be "letters"

Answer (score 1):

That is called `cartesian product`.

You can use ES6 features in order to achieve this: `reduce` and `map` methods.

> In set theory (and, usually, in other parts of mathematics), a
>   Cartesian product is a mathematical operation that returns a set from
>   multiple sets.

```js
function cartesianProduct(array ,n) {
  arrayToWork = [];
  for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
    arrayToWork.push(array);
  return arrayToWork.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
}
console.log(cartesianProduct(['A','B','C','D','E','F'],3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is `i < letters.length`, you probably want `i < alphabet.length` or `i < n`.
EDIT: The problem seems to be more fundamental. Doing this recursively is hard because you can't just write a letter at each step, since each 'leaf' of the recursion tree requires that letter to be written. Instead, you can add an array `chosen` as function argument that contains the letters chosen so far. Then, at `n===0`, you can print the chosen letters.

For example:

```js
var letters= ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

function myRekursion(alphabet, n, chosen){
  if(n > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
      var newChosen = chosen.slice(); //this copies the array
      newChosen.push(alphabet[i]); 
      myRekursion(alphabet, n - 1, newChosen);
    }
  } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < chosen.length; i++) {
      document.write(chosen[i]);
    }
    document.write(',<br />');
  }
}
myRekursion(letters, 3, []);
```

Comment: I see the point. I did not copy the array and continued to work on the copy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).

You could take a recursive approach by taking a temporary array for the previously collected values and check this array against the wanted length. If you got the amount of elements, display the actual array and leave the recusion.

If not iterate the elements of the given array and concat the actual element to the temporary array and call the function again.

```js
function getCombinations(array, n) {
    function iter(temp) {
        var i;
        if (temp.length === n) {
            result.push(temp.join(''));
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            iter(temp.concat(array[i]));
        }
    }
    var result = [];
    iter([]);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.