# Obtaining recursively permutations of a single list

Tags: python, list, subset, permutation, combinatorics

I am working in Python and I would like to obtain some kind of 'permutations' of a single list. I will make my best to explain the problem, but let me know if there is any doubt.

Imagine we have a list of strings `a = ['?','A','A','A']`, i.e. there are three `'A'` elements: `n=3`. I would like to create a method to obtain all the permutations of the `'A'`s (and the rest of the elements being `'?'`), decrementally, in the sense that in each 'permutation layer', the number of `'A'`s is decremented by one: `n=n-1`.

With examples, this is understood much better:

E.g., for `a` we would obtain `a0 = ['?','A','A','?']`, `a1 = ['?','A','?','A']` and and `a2 = ['?','?','A','A']` in the first 'permutation layer' `(n=3-1)`. In the same way, in the second 'permutation layer' (`n=3-1-1`); for `a0` we would have `a00 = ['?','A','?','?']` and `a01 = ['?','?','A','?']`, for `a1` we would have `a10 = ['?','A','?','?']` and `a11 = ['?','?','?','A']` and for `a2` we would have `a20 = ['?','?','A','?']` and `a21 = ['?','?','?','A']`. I know some of them can be redundant, for instance, `a00` and `a10`; there is no problem with that.

Note that there are no more permutation layers once `n=1` is reached, since every result would be `aN = ['?','?','?','?']`.

**A clarification**: the layer DOES matter, since I want to test whether a list holds a property (not important to mention) to get deeper on the layer. I will explain better: if a0 holds that property, then we explore a00 and a01, else we will not. This way, we potentially do NOT explore all the permutations. Thus, I only need the method that, given a list, obtains the permutations of the immediately NEXT layer, not the rest of them. In case `n=1`, returns whatever, say `foo`.

I do not know how to find about this or similar problems (indeed, is it correct to talk about permutations?). The closest post here seems to be [Recursive list of permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165768/recursive-list-of-permutations), where terms like 'cartesian product' and 'combinations with repetition' are mentioned. But the problem is not the same.

I do not care which method is used to reach the solution, I am not looking for efficiency; however, I have the feeling that this can be done in an elegant way doing recursion over `n`.

Can anyone solve my problem? I would appreciate the code is given in Python or a similar language.

**EDIT 1**

Using `itertools.permutations()` does not produce the desired results:

```
import itertools
a = ['?', 'A', 'A', 'A']

b = itertools.permutations(a)
for j in list(b): 
    print(j)
```

This prints:

```
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
```

Note that there is no single one of the expected results in there, since the number of `A`s has not been decremented.

Comment: Does the layer matter, or do you just want all the permutations (possibly with redundancies)?

Comment: Can you use `itertools.permutations()`?

Comment: Hello, @ScottHunter, thanks for the question! The layer DOES matter, since I want to test whether a list holds a property (not important to mention) to get deeper on the layer. I will explain better: if `a0` holds that property, then we explore `a00` and `a01`, else we will not. This way, we potentially do NOT explore all the permutations.

Comment: Hi, @Barmar I, thanks for the answer! I do not know, will try it now!

Comment: Thus, I only need the method that, given a list, obtains the permutations of the immediately NEXT layer, not the rest of them. In case `n=1`, returns whatever, say `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't really permutations.  They are the product of 4 ['A','?'] lists.

You could get them without recursion using itertool's product function:

```
from itertools import product

for p in product(*['A?']*4): print(p)
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', '?')
('A', 'A', '?', 'A')
('A', 'A', '?', '?')
('A', '?', 'A', 'A')
('A', '?', 'A', '?')
('A', '?', '?', 'A')
('A', '?', '?', '?')
('?', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('?', 'A', 'A', '?')
('?', 'A', '?', 'A')
('?', 'A', '?', '?')
('?', '?', 'A', 'A')
('?', '?', 'A', '?')
('?', '?', '?', 'A')
('?', '?', '?', '?')
```

For a recursive version, you can pass down each value (A or ? down the recursion with n-1 as the count:

```
def prod(values,n,result=[]):
    for v in values:
        if n == 1: yield [*result,v]
        else: yield from prod(values,n-1,[*result,v])
```

Comment: I have been able to solve the problem using a modification of this code! Thanks a lot! Should I post it in another EDIT?

Comment: Yes, please post your final solution. It may help people who find this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a way to list all of the ways to replace some subset of the `A`s with `?`s, which means it is the same as finding all of the ways to choose a subset of the `A`s (which `itertools` has code for).

Comment: Hello!! If the code is `permutations` (as it has been suggested in another comment), this does not produce the desired results: see the EDIT 1 in the post.